# Finding a functional form, solving a differential equation

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving

I am giving my actual problem, but I would also like to understand how to solve such problems in general. I am neither a mathematician nor do I know a lot about Mathematica.

I am looking for a function $y(x,n,q)$ and I have the following equation solving $\overline x$
$$
\frac{2}{3} = \sum_{k=0}^{q-1} {n \choose k} (1-\overline x)^k (\overline x)^{n-k}, 
$$
and $y(x,n,q)$ should be equal to
$$\frac{1}{1- 
\sum_{k=0}^{q-1} {n \choose k} (1-\overline x+ \int_x^{\overline x}\frac{3-y(z,n,q)}{3} dz )^k (\overline x- \int_x^{\overline x}\frac{3-y(z,n,q)}{3} dz )^{n-k}},$$
and combined these two then yield $y(\overline x,n,q)=3$.

My approach was to convert this into the following differential equation 
with $\frac{\partial u(x,n,q)}{\partial x}=y(x,n,q)$, i.e,
using

$$  \int_x^{\overline x}\frac{3-y(z,n,q)}{3} dz = \overline{x} - x -\frac{u(\overline x,n,q)-u(x,n,q)}{3}, $$

such that

$$
 \frac{\partial u(x,n,q)}{\partial x} = \frac{1}{1-  \sum_{k=0}^{q-1} {n \choose k} (1-  x - \frac{u(\overline{x},n,q)-u(x,n,q)}{3} )^k (x + \frac{u(\overline{x},n,q)-u(x,n,q)}{3})^{n-k}}. 
$$

Let us say I want to solve this for $q=2$ and $n=10$.

```
NSolve[{2/3 ==    Sum[Binomial[10, k] (1 - xbar)^k (xbar)^(10 - k), {k, 0, 2 - 1}],   1 >= wbar >= 0}, xbar, Reals]
```

gives me 0.8821589036184635` and

```
NDSolve[{y'[x] == 
1/(1 - Sum[
    Binomial[10, k] (1 - x - (y[0.8821589036184635`] - y[x])/3)^
     k (x + (y[0.8821589036184635`] - y[x])/3)^(10 - k), {k, 0, 
     2 - 1}]), y'[0.8821589036184635`] == 3},   y, {x, 0, 1}] // Simplify
```

> NDSolve::icordinit: The initial values for all the dependent variables
>   are not explicitly specified. NDSolve will attempt to find consistent
>   initial conditions for all the variables. NDSolve::idelay: Initial
>   history needs to be specified for all variables for delay-differential
>   equations.

while the same with DSolve gives me

> DSolve::bvnul: For some branches of the general solution, the given boundary conditions lead to an empty solution.

However, at least in my imagination, the function I am looking for should not be that complicated. So I am at a loss why Mathematica has an issue here. What am I doing wrong?

EDIT: 
The curve I am looking for should intuitively look like this [image]
This is how it would look like in MatLab, but I would love to play with it in Mathematica.
    q=3;
    n=10;

```
syms C k;
summand = nchoosek(n, k)*(1-C)^k * C^(n-k);
C_sum = sum(subs(summand, k, 0:q-1))-2/3; 

assume(C, 'real');
assume(C > 0);
C_sol = solve(C_sum, C);
C = C_sol

syms L x;
summand_nom = nchoosek(n, k)* (1-C+int((3-L)/3, x, C))^k * (C-int((3-L)/3, x, C))^(n-k);
nom = 1 - sum(subs(summand_nom, k, 0:q-1));
L = 1/nom;

figure()
eval_x = linspace(0,1,100);
plot(eval_x, subs(L, x, eval_x))
```

Comment: Using Root[2 - 30 #1^9 + 27 #1^10 &, 1] instead of 0.88215... also doesn't seem to help.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a problem with a parameter that can be solved using `ParametricNDSolve[]`

```
x0 = 
 xbar /. First[
   NSolve[{2/3 == 
      Sum[Binomial[10, k] (1 - xbar)^k (xbar)^(10 - k), {k, 0, 
        2 - 1}], 1 >= xbar >= 0}, xbar, Reals]]

(*Out[]= 0.882159*)
sol = ParametricNDSolve[{u'[x] == 
    1/(1 - Sum[
        Binomial[10, k] (1 - x - (p - u[x])/3)^
          k (x + (p - u[x])/3)^(10 - k), {k, 0, 2 - 1}]), u[0] == 0}, 
  u, {x, 0, 1}, {p}];
p0 = p /. FindRoot[Evaluate[u[p][x0] /. sol] == p, {p, 1}]

(*Out[]= 2.64648*)
Plot[u[p0][x] /. sol, {x, 0, 1}, AxesLabel -> {"x", "u"}, 
 Epilog -> {Red, PointSize[Medium], Point[{x0, p0}]}]
```

[image: Figure 1]